# Access sd card in android while the device is connected to the PC

Tags: android

In my android application, I am able to write files to the sd card. But I want to write a file to the sd card while the device connected to the PC. Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: If your sdcard is mounted on system(pc) then its not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know it is not possible for android to access the sd card while the sdcard is connected to the pc via usb.

however you can install any ftp- or sshd-server on android that can be accesses from pc when there is no usb-connection.

Update:

There are some free ftp-servers on google market like

- [lutey.FTPServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer&hl=en),
- [swiFtp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.swiftp&feature=related_apps)

Comment: can u please describe about the mini ftp-server?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. While the sd card is mounted by the PC it is no longer available to Android.